# Ranges in IF statements for Excel

Tags: function, vba, loops, excel

I'm working on a custom excel spreadsheet for my employer.

I have come up with a very nasty function that does what I want it to, but I would love to simplify it.

I'm familiar with `C`, `C#`, and `Java`. I would like to avoid using `VBA` if possible, but if that's my only option, I may consider using it.

I'm working on a planning sheet for a manufacturing plant that handles orders and deducts materials from the inventory, etc. I have a page set up for all of the products that the plant produces. There are different materials used for each product. I currently have a nasty if statement that checks for a matching string between 2 tables and then populates some other cells with relevant information when it finds a match.

I currently have an if statement with 20 conditions! I would never do such a thing in a real program!

Is there anyway that I can essentially loop through a range of cells until a match is found and then go from there? Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

Tab: MoldInformation - Contains all of the necessary information of the products that the plant produces.
Tab: Orders - Contains all of the orders that customer's have placed.

In the Orders Tab the first cell is titled Mold, where the user would input a string, then within the orders tab there is information pertaining to the amount of materials that are required to produce the order. If a certain Mold is entered, the materials that correspond to that mold populate their respective tabs within the orders sheet.

All my calculations are fine and dandy, but my if statement looks like this:

> =IF(A3=MoldInformation!$A$3,E3/MoldInformation!$F$3,IF(A3=MoldInformation!A$4,E3/MoldInformation!$F$4,IF(A3=MoldInformation!A$5,E3/MoldInformation!$F$5,IF(A3=MoldInformation!A$6,E3/MoldInformation!$F$6,IF(A3=MoldInformation!A$7,E3/MoldInformation!$F$7,IF(A3=MoldInformation!A$8,E3/MoldInformation!$F$8,IF(A3=MoldInformation!A$9,E3/MoldInformation!F$9,IF(A3=MoldInformation!A$10,E3/MoldInformation!F$10, IF(A3=MoldInformation!A$11,E3/MoldInformation!F$11, IF(A3=MoldInformation!A$12,E3/MoldInformation!F$12, IF(A3=MoldInformation!A$13,E3/MoldInformation!F$13, IF(A3=MoldInformation!A$14,E3/MoldInformation!F$14, IF(A3=MoldInformation!A$15,E3/MoldInformation!F$15, IF(A3=MoldInformation!A$16,E3/MoldInformation!F$16, IF(A3=MoldInformation!A$17,E3/MoldInformation!F$17,  IF(A3=MoldInformation!A$18,E3/MoldInformation!F$18, IF(A3=MoldInformation!A$19,E3/MoldInformation!F$19, IF(A3=MoldInformation!H$3,E3/MoldInformation!M$3, IF(A3=MoldInformation!H$4,E3/MoldInformation!M$4, IF(A3=MoldInformation!H$5,E3/MoldInformation!M$5,          IF(A3="","")))))))))))))))))))))

That is hideous! Is there anyway that I can essentially have it 'loop' through each cell until it finds a match? Since it is only looking in one place and then pulling information from whatever row it finds a match in, I believe that this should be possible.

Can anyone help me out with this?

I appreciate any help that you can provide. As aforementioned, if I can avoid using VBA, that'd be great but if any of you know how I can accomplish something similar within a function, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Sincerely,

Gary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> That is hideous!

Hideous is an understatement :p

Your formula can be simply written as

`=IF(ISERROR(E3/VLOOKUP(A3,MoldInformation!A:F,6,0)),"",E3/VLOOKUP(A3,MoldInformation!A:F,6,0))`

What this will do is, it will find the value from Col F in the `MoldInformation` where the value in A (from `MoldInformation`) matches with `A3`

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Siddharth Routh, you're awesome! Thanks a billion! This worked wonders and is going to make my life much easier!